# How can I make use of the collection accepting Dapper.Contrib methods?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper, dapper-contrib

Dapper.Contrib (https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib) states that they have several methods accepting IEnumerable lists, however I can not seem to find any of these methods. Using .NET Core 2, is this an outdated readme.md or an incompatibility with .NET Core?

Missing methods:

```
int Insert<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool Update<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool Delete<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
```

I've already gotten it working with just regular Dapper and some SQL, but I am just interested where these methods are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same methods can be used for single objects or lists of objects. If you [check the source code](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs#L306) for Insert, it checks whether the `entityToInsert` is [an array or IEnumerable](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs#L317).

You should be able to write

```
myConnection.Insert(myListOfItems);
```

Comment: Ah, so it's not actually an overload? If so, that's the solution, thanks!